# Laravel 7x Testing. How to feature test with image posts

Tags: php, testing, post, laravel-7

I'm quite new to Feature testing and I keep tripping up over some tests. A main part of my application is posting images along with captions, and whatever other text the post requires, this also includes updating that said post or profile.

I've been trying to research how to test whether the post renders along with the caption and post, and the most common approach does not seem to be working for me. I'm not sure what post route to use, or if how I have written it up is correct. However I'll show the areas I beleive to be important below. Please let me know I have left anything out.

> PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use  App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()

    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['show']]);
    }

    **public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
        $image->save();

        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'caption' => $data['caption'],
            'image' => $imagePath,
        ]);

        return redirect('/profiles/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }**

}
```

> PostControllerTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tag;
use Tests\TestCase;

class PostControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_the_post_index_is_rendered()
    {
        // First The user is created
        $user = factory(User::class)->make();
        //act as user
        $this->actingAs($user);
        // Then we want to make sure a post index is rendered
        $response = $this->get('/');
        //
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }


    public function test_if_posts_are_created()
    {
        // First The user is created
        $user = factory(User::class)->make();

        Storage::fake('image');

        //act as user
        $this->actingAs($user)
            // Then we want to make sure a profile page is created
            ->post(route('post.store'), [
                'caption' => 'description of the post',
                'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('postimage.jpg')
            ]);

$imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);


        Storage::assertExists("storage/{$imagePath}" . $image->hashName());

        $this->assertDatabaseCount('posts', 1);
    }
}
```

> web.php (posts section)

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('post.index');
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostsController@create')->name('post.create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store')->name('post.store');
Route::get('/p/{post}', 'PostsController@show')->name('post.show');
```

Thank you.